# SQL issue on query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of the following form :

```
Id, Amount(int), Date, PayType(text), Channel(text), Period(int from 1 to 5)
```

Basically a person can pay several time using different channels and different paymenttype.

What I would like is the channel, paytype and total amount given by the contacts at each period, for contacts that gave the first time by the channel "TE" (but could have given by other channel later on).

So the results should be:

```
Id, Amount_Period1, PayType_Period1, Channel_Period1, Amount_Period2, PayType_Period2, PayType_Period2... etc until period5...
```

I can't figure out how to do this query, or to think of a simpler way to see if people that initially used the channel "TE" kept using it or used different ones....

Basically i am trying to build a history of channel used.

For example,
Contact 1 first payment was done by channel "TE", amount 65, PaymentType : "VI", on period 3... his second payment on period 5 by channel "WW", amount 30, PaymentType : "CH" etc....

Link to a sample sql file : [Sample](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=44231467692315083872)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help explain what you want.  What if someone has multiple records for a given period, for instance?

Comment: I edited my post and added the link to a sample sql file !

Comment: your link doesn't work for me by the way.

Comment: @GordonLinoff & Greg added new link (link1) should work ?

Comment: @Mickael_Paris this isn't sample data. This is data. 30K rows aren't really a sample...

Comment: @ConsiderMe my data its actually more than 700k rows....

Comment: @Mickael_Paris what I meant is that if you ask people to help you with the issue you got here on SO, you should take some time to prepare your question to help the community actually help you faster. This means a small sample of data presenting possible different occurences.

Comment: @ConsiderMe : Okay i'll prepare a new sample now :) sorry didn't understand the point !

Comment: @ConsiderMe it's done :) i updated the link !

Comment: @Mickael_Paris You should also avoid external links to data. Read here on how to do this properly: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/100013

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like:

```
Select ID, 
case when P1.period=1 then P1.Amount end as Amount_Period1,
case when P1.period=1 then P1.PayType end as PayType_Period1,
case when P1.period=1 then P1.Channel end as Channel_Period1,
case when P2.period=2 then P2.Amount end as Amount_Period2,
case when P2.period=2 then P2.PayType end as PayType_Period2,
case when P2.period=2 then P2.Channel end as Channel_Period2,
case when P3.period=3 then P3.Amount end as Amount_Period3,
case when P3.period=3 then P3.PayType end as PayType_Period3,
case when P3.period=3 then P3.Channel end as Channel_Period3,
case when P4.period=4 then P4.Amount end as Amount_Period4,
case when P4.period=4 then P4.PayType end as PayType_Period4,
case when P4.period=4 then P4.Channel end as Channel_Period4,
case when P5.period=5 then P5.Amount end as Amount_Period5,
case when P5.period=5 then P5.PayType end as PayType_Period5,
case when P5.period=5 then P5.Channel end as Channel_Period5
From Table P1
LEFT JOIN Table P2
 on P1.ID = P2.ID and P1.Period = 1 and P2.Period=2
LEFT JOIN table P3
 on P2.ID = P3.ID and P2.Period = 2 and P3.Period=3
LEFT JOIN table P4
 on P3.ID = P4.ID and P3.Period = 3 and P4.Period=4
LEFT JOIN table P5
 on P4.ID = P5.ID and P4.Period = 4 and P5.Period=5
```

What this does is 5 self joins to get all the records on the same "row" and uses a case statement to fill in the appropriate values.  But if you have multiple records in the same paytype/channel then you may want to sum amount and group by all the different channels and paytypes.

But as Gordan stated... if multiple ID's exist for a given period for same paytype and channel then you may need to do some aggregation...

Comment: One trouble is that they all come from the same table, "act", period being one of the column

Comment: thus the reason why 5 self joins.  The data is getting parsed out by period in each derived table/inline view.

Comment: Hmm.. looking at your udpated comment.. it appers payments could occur in random periods 2,5 for one ID 1,3,5 for another 2,4 for yet another.  is that correct?  if so I know why this only works in "a way" if no payment in period 1 then this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

most logical for me at this point would be something like that :

```
SELECT Id, Channel, PayType, Period, sum(amount)
FROM unknown_table
GROUP by Id, PayType, Channel, Period
ORDER BY Id, Period, Date; -- for example
```

(you can use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to share your sample)